# Gis2web - QGIS plugin troubles

Tags: qgis, leaflet, openlayers-2, qgis2web

I have QGIS 2.6.1 and when I want to get some results using gis2web (by Tom Chadwin) plugin, in fact, to get a webmap in OpenLayers, it seems that plugin doesn't work properly.
E.g. I have a point layer and when I exported with this plugin, the points' labels are overlapped on them.
Another thing that is "Highlight features" and "Show popups on hover" don't work either.
Had anyone any kind of this trouble with this plugin?
PS. I have gis2web 0.21.3 version.
[image: Example]

Comment: That is the default alignment of OL3 labels. You can tweak your output code to amend this, I think with these options: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/apidoc/ol.style.Text.html.

Comment: I'll look into the other issues. If you can raise them as individual issues on Github, they are more likely to get sorted.

Answer (score 1):

OL3 labelling has been improved in versions since your question. Highlight features has also been fixed. Show popups on hover is yet to be sorted out. Try v0.24.0, and see whether that improves matters for you.

Comment: Show popups on hover has also now been sorted.